# Given ClassA and SubclassA, if I use Google Guice to bind ClassA to SubclassA then will SubclassA be injected as an instance where ClassA gets called?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, guice, code-injection

Say I am given a scenario like this:

```
@Data
public class ClassA {
     private final String name = "ClassA";
     public ClassA(){
       //This constructor gets called anyway. Why?
     }
}


@Data
public class SubclassA extends ClassA {
     private final String subname = "SubclassA";
     @Inject
     public SubclassA(){
        //I would expect for ONLY this constructor to be called.
     }
}


public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
     @Override
     protected void setup(){
       bind(ClassA.class).to(SubclassA.class);
     }
}


public class Main {
     public static void main(String [] args){
       Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
       ClassA classA = injector.getInstance(ClassA.class);
     }
}
```

Some of my questions:

- **Why are both constructors called?**
- **Is the object classA an instance of ClassA or SubclassA?**

Thanks

Comment: It's odd that `ClassA` is neither `abstract` nor an `interface`.  Does your `SubclassA` constructor call `super()` at any point?guice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is the object classA an instance of ClassA or SubclassA?
  Strictly sparking, classA's type is SubClassA.
- Why are both constructors called?
  Because SubClassA is a subclass of ClassA, when creating an instance of SubClassA, its parent class's constructor is also called.